# Winamp does not stay on top

Tags: windows-7, winamp

One thing I love about Winamp is its compact size, and *being able to stay on top*. For the past month or so, it won't stay on top.

I have tried:

- restarting the program: **No change**
- unchecking/rechecking the 'Always on Top' menu option: **No change**
- putting it on top of different programs, but as soon as the other programs get focus, it snaps back again: **No Change**
- changing the Theme from the Aero Windows 7 theme to just Windows Classic: **No change**
- changing the Winamp skin from Classic to Modern and even back again: **No change**
- uninstalling and reinstalling the application: **No change**.

What more can I try, or look into, to get Winamp to Stay On Top?

Comment: @CanadianLuke: Have you tried un-ticking **Options → Preferences... → General Preferences... → Disable always on top while fullscreen applications are focused**?

Comment: There is a relevant forum post about this workaround and others, don't know if it could be helpful: http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?threadid=213509

Comment: @James Thanks for the find, but it did not make a difference for me :(

Comment: @CanadianLuke: Have you tried different skins (e.g. modern) to see if it still occurs? Some people seem to think it can affect it.

Comment: I'm curious. Try using [this](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/quickly-enable-always-on-top-behaviour-for-any-app-or-window/) program and see if it makes it stay on top (temporary solution)

Comment: @ṧнʊß Weird... I downloaded the program (just an AHK script), but it didn't work. After I closed it and uninstalled that app, Winamp stayed on top!

Comment: @CanadianLuke That makes no sense! At least your problem is solved...? :) I want to know why this happened! The AHK script is `!t:: Winset, Alwaysontop, , A of code` apparently. So uninstalling it would have removed the hotkey, it shouldn't have fixed Winamp, but it's good it did!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although trying everything under the sun, I do not know exactly what fixed it. It is fixed now, but at what step, I do not know.

As posted in the comments above, I tried downloading [this program](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/quickly-enable-always-on-top-behaviour-for-any-app-or-window/) [recommended](https://superuser.com/questions/783459/winamp-does-not-stay-on-top?noredirect=1#comment1025716_783459) by [ṧнʊß](https://superuser.com/users/316136/%e1%b9%a7%d0%bd%ca%8a%c3%9f), but it didn't work. It was a simple AutoHotKey script.

I uninstalled it, since it never worked. After I uninstalled it, Winamp stayed on top. For reasons unknown, it just worked!

I'm calling this a bug in Winamp though. Even after a reboot, it's staying on top of my programs, and I can go back to my Aero interface :)